# What this sql query is wrong?

Tags: hibernate

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from FinancialTransactions where ft_TYPE='"+ftTYPE+"' Date between '"+beginDate+"' and '"+endDate+"'");
```

Whats wrong with above query? It gives error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed `and` there  and here `Date` is a keyword

change

```
where ft_TYPE='"+ftTYPE+"' Date between
```

to

```
where ft_TYPE='"+ftTYPE+"' and Date between
```

Between the various conditions you need to use `AND`

Comment: @user2294016 is it working for u now

Comment: i edited like you said but it says still SEVERE: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '04/18/2012 ' and ' 04/18/2013 )' at line 1
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Comment: Date is keyword.What is your column name

Comment: Date was working fine but when i added ft_TYPE it gives sql error

Comment: try to use ft_TYPE="+ftTYPE+"

Comment: @user2294016 did you tried this

Comment: even this query does not work why ? from FinancialTransactions where   FtType='Person'  and Date between '10/10/2012' and "10/18/2012"

Comment: can u run this is database directly .check this once in database

Answer (score 0):

If you use placeholders, the it becomes obvious that you've missed and `and`, also assuming `beginDate` and `endDate` are dates, it will probably have problems parsing them.

Better (and not prone to HQL injection) would be:

```
Query q = session.createQuery(
     "from FinancialTransactions " +
    "where ft_TYPE=? " +
      "and Date between ? and ?");
q.setString(1, ftType);
q.setDate(2, startDate);
q.setDate(3, endDate);
```